# In TikZ, how do I refer to the current background color?

Tags: tikz-pgf

When running some old TikZ code (that in 2019 used to work) I ran into the problem that apparently the string "bg" is passed to xcolor, instead of the current background color.  Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{gap/.style={circle,fill=bg,inner sep=1pt}}

\begin{document}

\[\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (00) at (0,0) {$A$};
  \node (20) at (2,0) {$B$};
  \draw (00) to node[gap]{g}(20);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\]

\end{document}
```

Replacing "bg" by "white" works, but in Beamer the background may not be white, so the result looks ugly.

This happens with LuaHBTeX, Version 1.13.2 (TeX Live 2021).

Comment: that never worked with article, `bg` is a color specific to beamer (and with beamer your example compiles).

Comment: Thank you!  That means I need different macros for Beamer and for regular papers. OK, that shouldn't bee too hard.

Answer (score 1):

You may alter your code as follows to be independend of the background color. There is no fill anymore and the line is split anyhow right in the middle:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{gap/.style={circle}}

\begin{document}

\[\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (00) at (0,0) {$A$};
  \node (20) at (2,0) {$B$};
  \path (00) to node [gap](g){g} (20);
  \draw (00) -- (g) -- (20);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\]

\end{document}
```